# SQL bulk insert with multiple fieldterminator

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

Please I need your help: I have this text file (notepad) that contain this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFew4.png)

I want to export the data from this txt file to sql table and sure I use bulk insert using this code:

```
Bulk insert table1
from 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.txt'
with
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

The problem here is I got 0 row effect when I run this code and this is because 
the field terminator between the words in the txt file, some times it's one tab and sometimes 2 tabs and one time is space and other time using this (;)

So what is the solution? how can I put more than one FIELDTERMINATOR  or if I can make it automatic see those terminators ?

Please I also have another question on the same example: how can I make ID field with auto increment, because in SQL when I put the id column here it give me wrong info because he start importing the data from first column. can I make any thing so the bulk insert start from the second field on the data base and leave the first one because its for the id ?

Thanks you very much

Comment: ok thank you I added it

Comment: If I were you I'd open up that text file and using Excel or Notepad++ replace (with a regex or otherwise) each of the different delimiters with a common one.  Trying to have SQL handle that would be tricky.

Comment: thank you but thats not gonna work because not allowed here to use excel or any other program

Answer (score 0):

"If you want to use a data file with fewer or more fields, we can implement via setting extra field length to 0 for fewer fields or omitting or skipping more fields during the bulk copy procedure."

More Information here :

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0376e883-33d7-4adf-935e-5ec64873e59e/forum-faq-how-to-use-multiple-field-terminators-in-bulk-insert-or-bcp-command-line?forum=sqltools